# How do I divide the remaining horizontal space between two columns in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I have an html table with say 5 columns.  Three of the columns I want to have a fixed width (for example, td width=30,50,30).  How would I divide the remaining horizontal space between the two remaining columns?  I thought I would do it by just setting each of the "width" properties for those columns to "50%", but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my simple test, I didn't have to put anything and the default behavior was to split evenly.   Of course, real content may push things around, so seeing your css and html would help.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                    td{border:1px solid #000; padding:1px;}
            </style>
    </head>
<body>

        <table width="300px">
        <tr><td width="50px"></td><td width="30px"></td><td width="50px"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doing what I thought would not work does actually work.  It was not working because I was overriding the default behavior elsewhere in my page through CSS.  Once I fixed that, it did work by setting the remaining columns each to 50%

Comment: There you go, glad you got it fixed up :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two columns with the space split, have one column, nest another table inside of it, and put two columns on the nested table each with a width of 50%.

Comment: @Byron - oh yeah, gotta love tables :)

Comment: Isn't there a more straight forward way to do it using the "WIDTH" property?  This must be a pretty common thing to have to do.